# Is there any way to make generic methods respect covariance in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

If I have these types:

```
public interface IVehicle { }

public class Ship : IVehicle { }

public interface IDesign<out T> where T : IVehicle { }

public class Design<T> : IDesign<T> where T : IVehicle { }
```

Then this method works just fine:

```
void MakeDesign1()
{
    ICollection<IDesign<IVehicle>> list = new List<IDesign<IVehicle>>();
    var design = new Design<Ship>();
    list.Add(design);
}
```

However a generic version does not:

```
void MakeDesign2<T>()
    where T : IVehicle
{
    ICollection<IDesign<IVehicle>> list = new List<IDesign<IVehicle>>();
    var design = new Design<T>();
    list.Add(design);
}
```

I get a compile error

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from `Design<T>` to `IDesign<IVehicle>`

Why is this? `IDesign<T>`'s type parameter is constrained to `IVehicle`, and it's covariant, so surely any `Design<T>` would be an `IDesign<Vehicle>`?

Is there any way to work around this without creating a dummy `IDesign` interface without a type parameter for `IDesign<T>` to inherit from? I was doing that before but it got really messy when it came to defining methods in concrete types like `Design<T>`! Weird things like coalescing generic methods causing errors...